# is it possible to give each marker in react-leaflet individual classname?

Tags: react-leaflet

I am using react-leaflet and rc-tabs and while selecting different row in a table I want to display appropriate marker. I want to draw a line from a row to a certain marker when hover with the help of react-lineto, which accepts only classNames as points (well, coordinates too, but this is not suitable for me) so I need an individual class of a marker, a class that can determine a marker on map.

How can I achieve that?

It seems there is no className attribute for every marker, just for group of markers...

Comment: there is similar question with no answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55992495/how-to-render-a-react-component-after-all-other-elements-of-the-page

Answer (score 0):

okey, after a day spent here I made an marker's icon classnames unique and after that draw a line between my table's hovered row and marker on the map.

```js
    return (
        <LeafMap center={[deviceCoordinatesLat, deviceCoordinatesLong]} zoom={14} style={{height: "90vh"}}>
            <TileLayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                       attribution="&copy; <a href=&quot;http://osm.org/copyright&quot;>OpenStreetMap</a> contributors"
            />


            {props.devices.map(device => (

                <Marker
                    className={device.serial}
                    key={device.id}
                    position={[degreesToCoord(device.coordinates)[0], degreesToCoord(device.coordinates)[1]]}
                    icon={hoveredItem.id === device.id ?


                        markerBigBlue :
                        new L.Icon({
                            iconUrl: require('../little-blue-dot.png'),
                            iconSize: new L.Point(15, 15),
                            className: "little-blue-dot-" + device.id
                        })
                    }
                >
                    {hoveredItem.id === device.id ?
                        <LineTo
                            *from={"leaflet-marker-icon little-blue-dot-" + device.id + " leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-interactive"}*
                            to={"invisible-blue-dot-" + device.id}
                            borderWidth={1}
                            zIndex={100}
                            borderColor="#0C86B8"
                        />
                        : <div></div>}
                    <Popup>
                        <span>{device.model} {device.serial}</span>
                    </Popup>}
                </Marker>
            ))}
        </LeafMap>
    )
```